# What happens when IIS sees the word set in a URL?

Tags: iis, asp-classic

Having a strange issue - we have a page that uses a query string to get some information, this query string happens to contain the word `set`. When this happens, the page returns a 406 error (`Client browser does not accept the MIME type of the requested page.`)

The URL looks like `example.com/folder/file.asp?variable=sunset boulevard`. If I change the space to `%20` it still returns 406.

On my local machine running IIS 5.x this doesn't happen, on our test server running IIS 7.x this doesn't happen, only on our production server running IIS 7.x over SSL. Note however that a self signed certificate on my local machine over SSL still doesn't produce the error.

So my question is, what does the `set` keyword in the URL tell IIS to do and is there an easy way to avoid it happening? I would like to avoid changing the space to a different character if possible.

Comment: You've established its the presence of the character sequence `set` that is actually the problem?  Its not even the word "set" since the word is actually "sunset".  Does your server have additional filters installed?  Smells like the work of an agressive filter design to prevent certain types of attack.

Comment: It is indeed the word `set` with the presence of a space after. `setstuff` is fine, `set` is fine, `set stuff` is not. I'll have to confirm with the server guys but I highly doubt they're setting any additional filters.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones It turns out SecureIIS by default grabs `set` within the querystring. If you want to post your comment an answer I'd be happy to mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your server have additional filters installed? Smells like the work of an agressive filter designed to prevent certain types of attack.